# How to use Jooq to query for a column case-insensitive?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

I am using jOOQ with PostgreSQL, and I just realize that my column is case sensitive.
Using jOOQ, I didn't found a correct method to query a column, ignoring its case sensitivity.
Looking at here : [jOOQ TableField Method](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#equalIgnoreCase%28org.jooq.Field%29), I can see that there's `equalIgnoreCase`. But in the jooq class itself, that method is not there.

Does anybody know what did I do wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure what could be the problem here (see my answer). Could you maybe provide an example of the code that is not working as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if by "case sensitivity", you mean the column content, or the column name.

- If you mean the column content, then you found the right method: [`Field.equalIgnoreCase()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#equalIgnoreCase%28org.jooq.Field%29). A usage example:

  ```
  create.select()
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(MY_TABLE.MY_FIELD.equalIgnoreCase("abc"))
        .fetch();
  ```
- If, however, you mean the column name, then you can use the `Factory` `Settings` to control how jOOQ renders field and column names. The relevant setting is [`RenderNameStyle`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/conf/RenderNameStyle.html)

Comment: Your respon is correct. Last night I just thinking that maybe I use an older version, 2.0.1. Having check in http://www.jooq.org/notes.php?version=2.1, this new method `equalIgnoreCase` is just available in 2.0.5. So, I change my `pom.xml` into that, and that method is available! Thanks

Comment: @swdev: I see. Note that you can find some [historic Javadocs here](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/)